# react-native starting app errors on Android Studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Title: Gradle build error: Could not find implementation class 'com.facebook.react.ReactPlugin'

Question:
I'm encountering an error while building my React Native project with Gradle. The error message states:

```
Could not find implementation class 'com.facebook.react.ReactPlugin' for plugin 'com.facebook.react' specified in jar:file:/Users/venkateshdasari/.gradle/caches/jars-9/410fa8799cd716bf29225aa40627be5f/react-native-gradle-plugin.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.facebook.react.properties.
```

Additionally, the error mentions that the `compileSdkVersion` is not specified in my `build.gradle` file.

I have tried clearing the Gradle cache, deleting the specific cache files mentioned in the error, and invalidating caches in Android Studio, but the issue still persists.

Here are the relevant details of my project setup:

- React Native version: [your React Native version]
- Gradle version: [your Gradle version]
- Other relevant dependencies: [list any relevant dependencies]

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

`[ React Native version 7.3.1 ]` and `[your Gradle version new ]` with the actual versions you're using. Also, include any additional relevant information about your project configuration and dependencies.

I tried to create an app in Android Studio but it is not working throwing this error always:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find implementation class 'com.facebook.react.ReactPlugin' for plugin 'com.facebook.react' specified in jar:file:/Users/venkateshdasari/.gradle/caches/jars-9/410fa8799cd716bf29225aa40627be5f/react-native-gradle-plugin.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.facebook.react.properties.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/venkateshdasari/FirstProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find implementation class 'com.facebook.react.ReactPlugin' for plugin 'com.facebook.react' specified in jar:file:/Users/venkateshdasari/.gradle/caches/jars-9/410fa8799cd716bf29225aa40627be5f/react-native-gradle-plugin.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.facebook.react.properties.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not very clear.

but still, from what I understood, you can try doing this step by step.

1. Check your `android/build.gradle` file:

```js
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31 // make sure this line is present
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    }
    }
```

```
In your `android/app/build.gradle`:
```

```js
 android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion // This line must be added if it is not there
    }
```

2. Do the following:

> Delete `node_module` folder and `package-lock.json` file
> from your root directory.
>
> Go to android folder and delete `.gradle` folder.
>
> Go to Android Studio ===> `Build` ===> `Clean Project`
>
> select `File` ===> `Invalidate Caches` ===> **check** *clear system files and local history*

```
this will restart the android studio
```

> 3. Go to terminal
>    in your Root project, enter command : `npm i --save`
>
> after that, `cd android; ./gradlew clean; cd ..` //*this will clean gradle files*
>
> then run, `npx react-native start --reset-cache`
>
> after that, run `npx react-native run-android`